# Python - Problem extracting data from nested json

Tags: python, json

I have a problem extracting data from json, I tried n different ways. I was able to extract the ID itself, unfortunately I can't manage to show the details of the field.

Below is my json

```
{
    "params": {
        "cid": "15482782896",
        "datemax": "20190831",
        "datemin": "20190601",
        "domains": [
            "url.com"
        ],

    },
    "results": {
        "59107": {
            "url.com": {
                "1946592": {
                    "data": {
                        "2019-06-01": {
                            "ENGINE": {
                                "DEVICE": {
                                    "": {
                                        "position": 21,
                                        "url": "url3.com"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "2019-07-01": {
                            "ENGINE": {
                                "DEVICE": {
                                    "": {
                                        "position": 4,
                                        "url": "url3.com"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "2019-08-01": {
                            "ENGINE": {
                                "DEVICE": {
                                    "": {
                                        "position": 2,
                                        "url": "url3.com"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "keyword": {
                        "title": "python_1",
                        "volume": 10
                    }
                },
                "1946602": {
                    "data": {
                        "2019-06-01": {
                            "ENGINE": {
                                "DEVICE": {
                                    "": {
                                        "position": 5,
                                        "url": "url1.com"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "2019-07-01": {
                            "ENGINE": {
                                "DEVICE": {
                                    "": {
                                        "position": 12,
                                        "url": "url1.com"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "2019-08-01": {
                            "ENGINE": {
                                "DEVICE": {
                                    "": {
                                        "position": 10.25,
                                        "url": "url1.com"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "keyword": {
                        "title": "python_2",
                        "volume": 20
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following code but I got the result in the form of id itself

```
import json
import csv

def get_leaves(item, key=None):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        leaves = {}
        for i in item.keys():
            leaves.update(get_leaves(item[i], i))
        return leaves
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        leaves = {}
        for i in item:
            leaves.update(get_leaves(i, key))
        return leaves
    else:
        return {key : item}


with open('me_filename') as f_input:
    json_data = json.load(f_input)

fieldnames = set()

for entry in json_data:
    fieldnames.update(get_leaves(entry).keys())

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=sorted(fieldnames))
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerows(get_leaves(entry) for entry in json_data)
```

I also tried to use the pandas but also failed to parse properly

```
import io
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('me_filename', encoding='utf-8') as f_input:
    df = pd.read_json(f_input , orient='None')

df.to_csv('output.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

The result I'd need to get it :

```
ID      Name         page   volume  url      2019-06-01 2019-07-01  2019-08-01  2019-09-01
1946592 python_1    url.com 10      url3.com    21   4    2 null
1946602 python_2    url.com 20      url1.com    5   12  10,25   null
```

What could I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm this is a bit of a convoluted solution and it looks very messy and no-longer looks like the code provided however I believe it will resolve your issue.

First of all I had a problem with the provided Json (due to the trailing ',' on line 8) however have managed to generate:

## Output (temp.csv)

```
ID,Name,Page,Volume,Url,2019-08-01,2019-07-01,2019-06-01,
1946592,python_1,url.com,10,url3.com,2,4,21,
1946602,python_2,url.com,20,url1.com,10.25,12,5,
```

using the following:

```py
import json

dates: set = set()

# Collect the data 
def get_breakdown(json):
    collected_data = []
    for result in json['results']:
        for page in json['results'][result]:
            for _id in json['results'][result][page]:
                data_struct = { 
                    'ID': _id, 
                    'Name': json['results'][result][page][_id]['keyword']['title'], 
                    'Page': page, 
                    'Volume': json['results'][result][page][_id]['keyword']['volume'], 
                    'Dates': {}
                }
                for date in dates:
                    if date in json['results'][result][page][_id]['data']:
                        data_struct['URL'] = json['results'][result][page][_id]['data'][date]['ENGINE']['DEVICE']['']['url']
                        data_struct['Dates'][date] = {'Position' : json['results'][result][page][_id]['data'][date]['ENGINE']['DEVICE']['']['position']}
                    else:
                        data_struct['Dates'][date] = {'Position' : 'null'}
                collected_data.append(data_struct)
    return collected_data

# Collect all dates across the whole data 
# structure and save them to a set
def get_dates(json):
    for result in json['results']:
        for page in json['results'][result]:
            for _id in json['results'][result][page]:
                for date in json['results'][result][page][_id]['data']:
                    dates.add(date)


# Write to .csv file
def write_csv(collected_data, file_path):
    f = open(file_path, "w")
    # CSV Title
    date_string = ''
    for date in dates:
        date_string = '{0}{1},'.format(date_string, date)
    f.write('ID,Name,Page,Volume,Url,{0}\n'.format(date_string))

    # Data
    for data in collected_data:
        position_string = ''
        for date in dates:
            position_string = '{0}{1},'.format(position_string, data['Dates'][date]['Position'])
        f.write('{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}\n'.format(
            data['ID'],
            data['Name'],
            data['Page'],
            data['Volume'],
            data['URL'],
            position_string
        ))

# Code Body
with open('me_filename.json') as f_input:
    json_data = json.load(f_input)
    get_dates(json_data)
    write_csv(get_breakdown(json_data), "output.csv")
```

Hopefully you can follow the code and it does what is expected. I am sure that it can be made much more reliable - however as previously mentioned I couldn't make it work with the base code you provided.

Comment: Great, works. Thank you very much
And I wonder if it would be better to do that in csv file:

`ID,Name,Page,Volume,Url,data,value,
1946592,python_1,url.com,10,url3.com,2019-08-01,2
1946592,python_1,url.com,10,url3.com,2019-07-01,4
1946592,python_1,url.com,10,url3.com,2019-06-01,21
1946602,python_2,url.com,20,url1.com,2019-08-01,10.25,
1946602,python_2,url.com,20,url1.com,2019-07-01,12,
1946602,python_2,url.com,20,url1.com,2019-06-01,5,`

Comment: @mario - I don't know the requirements so cannot make comment on if the suggested csv changes would be better for your solution, however it would allow you to remove a lot of the repetative tasks in the Code provided (and therefore make it more efficient) - also, as a side - if the answer is your chosen solution would you mind marking it as the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a small modification your code works great, but I noticed that showing the date as the next line would be a better solution in the format.
I tried to modify your solution to this form, but I'm still too weak in python to easily deal with it. Can you still tell me how you can do it to achieve this csv file format?

**Output(temp.csv)**

```
ID,Name,Page,Volume,Url,data,value, 
1946592,python_1,url.com,10,url3.com,2019-08-01,2
1946592,python_1,url.com,10,url3.com,2019-07-01,4
1946592,python_1,url.com,10,url3.com,2019-06-01,21
1946602,python_2,url.com,20,url1.com,2019-08-01,10.25,
1946602,python_2,url.com,20,url1.com,2019-07-01,12,
1946602,python_2,url.com,20,url1.com,2019-06-01,5,
```